# Have Image Widget Replace Inkwell Widget After Being Tapped

Tags: flutter, dart

I have several InkWell widgets. When an InkWell is tapped, I want an Image widget to replace the InkWell widget.

The following is what I have thus far:

```
Widget viewForHandTile(int tileIndex, Tile tile) {
      return tile.getOnTap()
          ? InkWell(
              splashColor: Colors.black26,
              onTap: () {
                humanChoseTileFromHand = true;
                humansHandTileSelected = tile;
                indexOfHandTileSelected = tileIndex;

                setState(() {
                  humanPlayer.enableTileTapsInHumansHand();
                  tile.disableOnTap();
                });
              },
              child: Ink.image(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/${tile.getTileFace()}.png'),
                  height: 94.35,
                  width: 51,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover))
          : Image.asset('assets/${tile.getTileFace()}.png',
              height: 94.35, width: 51, fit: BoxFit.cover);
    }
```

I added setState(), but the InkWell being clicked on is still not turning into an Image. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

**Update:** I was able to fix the issue by moving a function that enables all of the InkWell onTaps out of the build.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the structure of the widget tree, you can use the IgnorePointer widget to remove the click from InkWell

Pay attention to the sample code below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  late bool clickable;

  @override
  void initState() {
    clickable = false;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: IgnorePointer(
          ignoring: clickable,
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              print("clicked");
              setState(() {
                clickable = true;
              });
            },
            child: Container(
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              color: Colors.cyan,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```